# Scala: cannot declare reference to function using supertypes

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

Apologies for the noob question, but I'm very new to Scala.

I have the following Scala class:

```
class Test {
    class Request {def getValue(): String = {"request"}}
    class Response {def getValue(): String = {"response"}}
    case class MyRequest(message: String) extends Request
    case class MyResponse(message: String) extends Response
    val myFunction: (Request) => Response = doSomething
    private val functions = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, (Request) => Response](
        "myFunction" -> myFunction
    )
    def doSomething(request: MyRequest): MyResponse = {
        null
    }
}
```

Which fails to compile with the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Test.this.MyRequest => Test.this.MyResponse
 required: Test.this.Request => Test.this.Response
    val myFunction: (Request) => Response = doSomething
```

It works if I change the declaration of myFunction and functions to:

```
val myFunction: (MyRequest) => MyResponse = doSomething
private val functions = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, (MyRequest) => MyResponse](
    "myFunction" -> myFunction
)
```

But this isn't what I want -- I want to be able to add other functions, with different concrete types (which all extend Request or Response), to the map. So I'd like to declare the map as taking any subclass of Request or Response.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the argument type of `doSomething` to `Request`, rather than `MyRequest` and it will work:

```
def doSomething(request: Request): MyResponse = {
    null
}
```

Why is this? Well you cannot assign a function with a more specific argument type to a variable with a less specific argument type. If `doSomething` had a argument type of `MyRequest` and in the body of `doSomething` we called a method that was only available on `MyRequest` and not available on `Request`, what would happen in the below example if someone called myFunction with a different implementation of `Request`? We would have broken the type safety.

```
val myFunction: (Request) => Response = doSomething
```

We can see this in the parameterised types on the `Function1` trait:

```
trait Function1[-T1, +R]
```

The `-T1` means that the argument of a Function is contravariant which means Functions with less specific argument types count as subtypes (i.e. a `Request => Response` Function can be assigned to a variable of type `MyRequest => Response`). The `+R` means that Function return types are covariant which means that `Function`s with more specific return types count as subtypes (i.e. `Request => MyResponse` can be assigned to a variable of type `Request => Response`).